# Rails printing array to selection_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to print an array to selection_tag

tried it this way:

```
 <%= f.select(:currency, {"€","$"} { |p| [p[0], p[1]] }, {}, {:class => "form-control"}) %>
```

But got an synthax error...

What's my failure?

Thanks

Comment: Post your error. And what's this? `{"€","$"} { |p| [p[0], p[1]] }`? Perhaps you mean `["€","$"].map { |p| [p[0], p[1]] }`?

Comment: This question means more context. What are output are you trying to achieve? This `{"€","$"} { |p| [p[0], p[1]] }` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I want a dropdown field with those two entries

Comment: @WesFoster That works partially, I got a Dropdown field, But no value is stored in database

Comment: @Felix try `["€","$"]` without the map

Comment: then I got synthax error:  syntax error, unexpected { arg, expecting ')' ...select(:currency, ["€","$"] { |p| [p[0], p[1]] }, {}, {:cl... ... ^

Comment: Please read the docs: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that [`options_for_select`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select) is the correct method to use in this context:

```
<%= f.select(:currency, options_for_select(['€', '$']), {}, class: 'form-control') %>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution

```
 <%= f.select(:currency, ["€","$"].map { |p| [p[0], p[0]] }, {}, {:class => "form-control"}) %>
```